# In python, communicating with stackdriver always returns success, doesn't send anything

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api-python-client, stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

For some inexplicable reason, google provides no stackdriver api for appengine, so I'm stuck implementing one. No worries - I thought - I have already worked with the API builder to talk to bigquery, so I built up a client and started trying to send events:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(STACKDRIVER_AUTH_GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
                                            STACKDRIVER_AUTH_GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
                                            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append')

http = httplib2.Http()
credentials.refresh(http) #Working around an oauth2client bug
credentials = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build('cloudtrace', 'v1', http=http)
batch = service.new_batch_http_request()
batch.add(service.projects().patchTraces(
        body=traces_json,
        projectId=STACKDRIVER_AUTH_GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID))
print batch.execute()
```

I left out the definition of traces_json because no matter what I send, the service always responds with an error. If traces_json = '{}':

```
{u'error': {u'code': 400,
            u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global',
                         u'message': u'Invalid value at \'traces\' (type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudtrace.v1.Traces), "{}"',
                         u'reason': u'badRequest'}],
            u'message': u'Invalid value at \'traces\' (type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudtrace.v1.Traces), "{}"',
            u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}
```

But even if I use a body, crafted from the google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/cloudtrace/v1/python/latest/cloudtrace_v1.projects.html), I still get the same error.

I'm running a packet sniffer on the machine where I'm attempting this, and only very rarely see it actually communicating with googleapis.com.

So the question is, really, what am I missing that will get me sending events to stackdriver?

**UPDATE**

Here's the most recent iteration of what I'd been working with, though using the google doc example verbatim (with the exception of changing the project id) produces the same result.

```
{
    "traces": [
        {
            "projectId": "projectname",
            "traceId": "1234123412341234aaaabb3412347890",
            "spans": [
                {
                    "kind": "RPC_SERVER",
                    "name": "trace_name",
                    "labels": {"label1": "value1", "label2": "value2"},
                    "spanId": "spanId1",
                    "startTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:23.045123456Z",
                    "endTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:23.945123456Z",
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
}
```

And the error message that comes with it:

```
{u'error': {u'code': 400,
            u'errors': [{u'domain': u'global',
                         u'message': u'Invalid value at \'traces\' (type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudtrace.v1.Traces), "MY ENTIRE JSON IS REPEATED HERE"',
                         u'reason': u'badRequest'}],
            u'message': u'Invalid value at \'traces\' (type.googleapis.com/google.devtools.cloudtrace.v1.Traces), "MY ENTIRE JSON IS REPEATED HERE"',
            u'status': u'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}}
```

**SECOND UPDATE**

Doing this in the explorer produces approximately the same result. I had to switch to a numeric span_id because, despite the docs' statement that it only has to be a unique string, I get errors about requiring what appears to be a 64-bit integer, any time I provide anything else.

```
PATCH https://cloudtrace.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[number or name]/traces?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
 "traces": [
  {
   "projectId": "[number or name]",
   "traceId": "1234123412341234aaaabb3412347891",
   "spans": [
    {
     "kind": "RPC_SERVER",
     "name": "trace_name",
     "labels": {
      "label1": "value1"
     },
     "startTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:23.045123456Z",
     "endTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:25.045123456Z"
    },
    {
     "spanId": "0"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

[image: Traces definition from the API "Try It!" page]

Comment: Your error is saying it's a badly formatted request.  Looking at the [formal definition](https://cloud.google.com/trace/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/patchTraces#traces) of the JSON request, there are constraints on the data, which the sample you linked to does not satisfy.  Have you tried setting feild values that exactly match the specification?  If so, what does your request look like and what error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the format of your data. You can not send empty messages either. The best way to explore how to use the API is to go to the StackDriver Trace API explorer, you will find out the exact data structure to send:
https://cloud.google.com/trace/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/patchTraces#traces

Pay special attention to the format of traceId. It needs to be 32 character hex string like this:  7d9d1a6e2d1f3f27484992f33d97e5cb

Here is a working python example to show how to use the 3 methods on StackDriver trace on github: https://github.com/qike/cloud-trace-samples-python

Copy paste code below:

```
def list_traces(stub, project_id):
    """Lists traces in the given project."""
    trace_id = None
    req = trace_pb2.ListTracesRequest(project_id=project_id)
    try:
        resp = stub.ListTraces(req, TIMEOUT)
        for t in resp.traces:
            trace_id = t.trace_id
            print("Trace is: {}".format(t.trace_id))
    except NetworkError, e:
        logging.warning('Failed to list traces: {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit(1)
    return trace_id


def patch_traces(stub, project_id):
    req = trace_pb2.PatchTracesRequest(project_id=project_id)
    trace_id = str(uuid.uuid1()).replace('-', '')
    now = time.time()

    trace = req.traces.traces.add()
    trace.project_id = project_id
    trace.trace_id = trace_id
    span1 = trace.spans.add()
    span1.span_id = 1
    span1.name = "/span1.{}".format(trace_id)
    span1.start_time.seconds = int(now)-10
    span1.end_time.seconds = int(now)

    span2 = trace.spans.add()
    span2.span_id = 2
    span2.name = "/span2"
    span2.start_time.seconds = int(now)-8
    span2.end_time.seconds = int(now)-5

    try:
        resp = stub.PatchTraces(req, TIMEOUT)
        print("Trace added successfully.\n"
              "To view list of traces, go to: "
              "http://console.cloud.google.com/traces/traces?project={}&tr=2\n"
              "To view this trace added, go to: "
              "http://console.cloud.google.com/traces/details/{}?project={}"
              .format(project_id, trace_id, project_id))
    except NetworkError, e:
        logging.warning('Failed to patch traces: {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit(1)


def get_trace(stub, project_id, trace_id):
    req = trace_pb2.GetTraceRequest(project_id=project_id,
                                    trace_id=trace_id)
    try:
        resp = stub.GetTrace(req, TIMEOUT)
        print("Trace retrieved: {}".format(resp))
    except NetworkError, e:
        logging.warning('Failed to get trace: {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit(1)
```

**UPDATED to answer error received from API explorer**

Regarding the errors you got from using API explorer, it was due to using 0 as span_id. It should be a 64 bit int other than 0.

I also observed that the span_id you set is in a different span object than the one you intended. Make sure you don't by mistake clicking on a "+" sign to add a new span object.

Below is a successful patch request I sent to my project through API explorer:

```
{
 "traces": [
  {
   "projectId": "<project ID>",  // I used string ID, not numeric number
   "traceId": "1234123412341234aaaabb3412347891",
   "spans": [
    {
     "spanId": "1",
     "name": "foo",
     "startTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:23.045123456Z",
     "endTime": "2016-06-01T05:01:25.045123456Z"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
Response

200
```

Comment: After installing everything to get that example to work, I get errors, saying that the trace API hasn't been enabled. However, the project_id that it gives is for that project doesn't belong to me. Regardless of which project_id I provide or whether I provide the name or numeric id, it always fails referencing #32555940559: NetworkError(code=StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED, details="Stackdriver Trace API has not been used in project 32555940559 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/cloudtrace/overview?project=32555940559 then retry.

Comment: That is an error you will get if you run `gcloud login` instead of `gcloud beta auth application-default login`. Please follow the instructions on the readme file, specifically step #2

Comment: I managed to get the demo running - the missing install of gax_google_devtools_cloudtrace_v1 took care of the issue. I'm now trying to get the example working from within the appengine environment, and I'm back to an exception on: "from grpc.beta import implementations:" "ImportError: No module named beta" (This is having done a pip install -t lib for gax_google_devtools_cloudtrace_v1, grpc, and grpcio, and adding lib to the appenginge_config.py's vendors.

Comment: gRPC on GAE is not supported yet. Google is working on it. But for your purpose, you do not need to use gRPC, use json and urlfetch like your original solution should work, now that you fixed the data problem.

Comment: See the "Second Update," above. Regardless of what Json I use, the original solution receives errors.

Comment: The error in your second update is because: 1) you used 0 for span id, that is not valid. 2) you put span_id in a separate span object than the one you wanted to put it in. Hence you ended up having 2 span objects, one without span_id, one with only span_id, which is invalid.